# Django restful api can not get file content

Tags: python, angularjs, django, rest

I use Django restful api + angularjs .
Now ,I append to use angularjs upload file to server by Django restful api 
On the web front-end ,The Html is:

```
<input type="file" data-upload-file id="uploadInputFile">
```

The angularjs's code is :

```
omapp.directive("uploadFile",function(httpPostFactory){
    return {
        restrict:"A",
        scope:true,
        link:function(scope,element,attr){
            element.bind('change',function(){
                var formData = new FormData();
                formData.append('file', element[0].files[0]);             
                console.log(formData.get('file'))         

    httpPostFactory('/api/uploadfile/',formData.get('file'),function (callback) {
                        console.log(callback);
                    })
                })
            }
        };

    });

omapp.factory('httpPostFactory', function ($http,$cookies) {
    return function (file, data, callback) {
                    var req = {
                         method:"POST",
                         url:file,
                         headers:{
                             'X-CSRFToken':$cookies.get('csrftoken')
                         },
                         data:{file:data}
                   }
                   $http(req)
                   .then(function successcallback(response){callback(response);})

    }
});
```

Everything is ok .But Django api can not get data
The code is :

```
 class UploadFile(APIView):
     def post(self,request,format=None):
         logger.info("file content");
         logger.info(request.data)
         return Response("upload done")
```

How can i get data ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to get from  **request.FILES**

```
def post(self,request,format=None):
     file_data = request.FILES['file']
     return Response("upload done")
```

Comment: when I use "request.FILES['file']",caught a error:angular.js:14727 Possibly unhandled rejection...

Comment: unhandled rejection ,it may be 500 key error.check your browser console ,your request data has file content,

Comment: I got a new error:MultiValueDictKeyError at /api/uploadfile/
"'file'"

Comment: can post your latest code chanes get this errror MultiValueDictKeyError at /api/uploadfile/ "'file'"

Answer (score 0):

The better way to handle file upload in django rest calls, use base64 formatting. In front end encode your file to base64 string and in django again decode it into original file. Sample code [here](https://matthewdaly.co.uk/blog/2015/07/04/handling-images-as-base64-strings-with-django-rest-framework/).

Answer (score 0):

I got the anwser:
The Html is :

```
<input type="file" data-upload-file id="uploadInputFile">
```

The angularjs is:

```
omapp.directive("uploadFile",function(httpPostFactory){
    return {
        restrict:"A",
        scope:true,
        link:function(scope,element,attr){
            element.bind('change',function(){
                var formData = new FormData();
                formData.append('file', element[0].files[0]);             
                console.log(formData.get('file'))         

    httpPostFactory('/api/uploadfile/',formData.get('file'),function (callback) {
                        console.log(callback);
                    })
                })
            }
        };

    });

omapp.factory('httpPostFactory', function ($http,$cookies) {
    return function (file, data, callback) {
                    var req = {
                         method:"POST",
                         url:file,
                         headers:{
                             'X-CSRFToken':$cookies.get('csrftoken'),
                              Content-Type': undefined //add this
                         },
                         data:{file:data}
                   }
                   $http(req)
                   .then(function successcallback(response){callback(response);})

    }
});
```

restful api:

```
class UploadFile(APIView):
     def post(self,request,format=None):
         logger.info("read file ");
         up_file = request.FILES['file']
         logger.info(up_file)
```